# How do I run GUI version of NetworkManager on DWM?

Tags: networking, command-line, network-manager

I was using `wicd-gtk` to connect to networks but for some reason it doesn't connect me to some networks and `NetworkManager` seems to be working fine.

How can I launch GUI version of `NetworkManager` if I am not using Unity but DWM?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Provided that your system includes the `network-manager-gnome` package (and its dependencies), you should be able to run NetworkManager's GUI connection editor from the command line using

```
nm-connection-editor
```

You can attempt to start the GUI desktop applet as `nm-applet`, however it may not be able to interact with / dock within a simple WM.

Comment: 'nm-connection-editor' works just fine but what I want is the applet, which doesn't seem to work on DWM.

Answer (score 2):

You need a system tray for the tray icon you want (nm-applet), which DWM doesn't provide by default. Their are a number of stand-alone tray programs for light weight window managers like DWM. You could try the venerable [stalonetray](http://stalonetray.sourceforge.net/) or [systray](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/systray), the latter of which is by the same author as DWM.